# Wp rewrite rules cpt/taxonomies/term/postname

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I have a CPT `products` and two custom taxonomies `products_brands` and `products_categories`. 
I can currently access my custom taxonomy via `domain/taxonomy/term` and product via `domain/product/postname`.

I want to change the URL in order to have something like this : `domain/products/taxonomy/term/postname`. Is it possible ?

I rode similar question https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108642/permalinks-custom-post-type-custom-taxonomy-post but in this case there is only one taxonomy.

Should I use `rewrite_rules` function ? Maybe I can match in the url the taxonomy name and the term and reinject it in a new url ?

Does somebody have an idea ?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ["Custom Permalinks"](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/) plugin to do this.

However it doesn't defaultly change your permalink structure. You've need to change your permalink structure for every post, when you create them.

You can arrange your permalink structure in any way with this plugin.